# How to prove the fundamental period of a periodic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, periodic-functions

The following is a simpler version of the problem at hand.

Lets say we have a periodic function $f$ which has a fundamental period $p>1$. That is, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$f(n) = f(n+p).$$ 
Similarly, we have two other periodic functions $g$ and $h$ such that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$g(n) = g(n+a), \quad h(n) = h(n+b),$$
where $a,b>1$ are the fundamental periods for $g$ and $h$, respectively. Additionally, we know $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $g(n) = h(n)$ only if $g(n) = 0 = h(n)$. The function $f$ is defined as
$$f(n) = \begin{cases}
g(n), & g(n) \neq 0; \\
h(n), & g(n) = 0. \\
\end{cases}$$
My question is: What is the fundamental period of $f$ in terms of $a$ and $b$? Or how do I prove what the fundamental period is?

My attempt: I've shown that $p \le ab$ by
$$f(n) = \begin{cases}
g(n), & g(n) \neq 0; \\
h(n), & g(n) = 0, \\
\end{cases} = f(n + ab) = \begin{cases}
g(n+ab), & g(n+ab) \neq 0; \\
h(n+ab), & g(n+ab) = 0. \\
\end{cases}$$
Also, I noticed that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$f(n)=g(n) = g(n+a) \text{ or } f(n) = h(n) = h(n+b)$$
and
$$g(n) \neq 0 \implies g(n) \neq h(n+b) \text{ and } h(n) \neq g(n+a).$$
From here, I am not sure where to go.

Comment: The fundamental period can vary, depending on $h$ and $g$. If $h \equiv 0$ or $g(n) \ne 0$ for all $n$, then the period is obviously $a$. if $g \equiv 0$, it will obviously be $b$. Otherwise it will be $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$. And since $a, b$ are given as coprime, that will be $ab$. (And since we are also given $a,b > 1$, it also cannot be that $g\equiv 0$ or $h \equiv 0$.)